# Help me to understand this /Users/username/sites/website1

Tags: macos, folders, user-account

Can anyone help me to understand the logic behind placing my /sites folder like this **/Users/username/sites/website1**
How do I find the Users folder?
I am using OS X El Capitan
Thank you

Comment: You have 2 questions: "why is `/sites` in my home folder" and "how do I find `Users` folder". Which is the problem you are having?

Comment: Hello. My question is how do I find my Users folder. I think I have the set up correct. My sites folder within the Home Name folder that I find under All My Files. So I guess I have it right.

Comment: Sigh... I just realized I have two Sites folders. I want to place the one that has my website folders into my /user directory and get rid of the one I have there. I guess it's just a matter of overwriting the original one there. How do I find my /user folder? Thanks.

Comment: Does this render the original question moot?

Answer (score 4):

The folder */Users* usually is in the root of your boot volume. The folder */Users* usually contains all user folders of the (non-system) accounts configured in OS X and a *Shared* folder. The name of a user folder usually is identical with the short name of the user account.

To see/access */Users* either open your boot volume or bring *Finder* to the foreground and in the menubar navigate to **Go To** -> **Go To Folder...**, enter `/` and hit the OK button (then you will see the folder *Users*) or enter `/Users` and hit the OK button (then you will see the content of the folder *Users*).

In **/Users/username/sites/website1** *username* is just a place holder for your (OS X) short name. So in */Users* open the folder with your OS X short name (your user or home folder is also indicated by its icon: a little house) and you are in your user folder.

To immediately jump into your user folder use the shortcut <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> in the Finder.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to navigate to folders in the Finder.

### Method 1: Navigate to the folder

Open a new Finder window and use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> arrow key to move up until you get to a common parent folder of the folder you want to find (so you will get all the way up to the computer). Then find the folder you want.

### Method 2: Go to folder

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> or click Go menu > Go to folder... and enter the path to the folder you want. Press Go. You will automatically be brought to that folder. For the Users folder, enter

```
/Users
```

Note that it isn't case sensitive. You can also press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to autocomplete folder names. If you have a folder at the path `~/Documents/MyFolderName` you can type `~/Documents/MyFol` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> and the first folder that starts with `MyFol` (in alphabetical order) will be autocompleted.

### Method 3: Common shortcuts

This isn't available for `/Users`, but it's useful to know. In the Go menu, there are various folders that you can quickly access. You can press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to go to your Home folder and press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> to get to `/Users` because your home folder is `/Users/username`.